# Enzyme test for empty array on componentWillUnMount dispatch action

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test whether the redux store changes to an empty array by checking the props on the container when I dispatch and action on componentWillUnMount.

So I mean, test the change ["foo", "bar"] from my redux reducer to an empty array `[]`.

My code looks as follows:

Container:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../../store/actions/actions';

class MyComponent extends Component{


    componentWillUnmount(){
        this.props.cleanSearch();
    }

    render(){
        
        return(
            <div>
                
               Whatever
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state=>{
    const itemsSearched = state.itemsSearched;
    return{
        itemsSearched
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>{

    return{
        cleanSearch: ()=> dispatch(actions.cleanSearch())
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```

My reducer:

```js
import {
    CLEAN_SEARCH
} from '../actions/types';

import * as utils from '../../utils/udpaterState';

const initialState = {
    itemsSearched: ["foo", "bar"]
}

const reducer= (prevState = initialState, action)=>{
    let newState = null;
    switch(action.type){
        case CLEAN_SEARCH:
            newState = {itemsSearched: []}
            return utils.updaterState(prevState, newState);
        default:
            return prevState;
    }
}


export default reducer;
```

And my test code looks like this:

MyComponent.test.js

```js
it('cleans redux prop searches when componentWillUnMount is called', ()=>{
        const spy = jest.spyOn(MyComponent.prototype, 'componentWillUnmount');
        const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent store={storeUtil} itemsSearched={mocks.itemsSearched()} />);
        expect(wrapper.props().itemsSearched).toEqual(mocks.itemsSearched());
        wrapper.instance().componentWillUnmount();
        expect(wrapper.props().itemsSearched).toEqual([]);

    })
```

However what I receive is the ["foo", "bar"] array instead of the empty expected one.

Answer (score 0):

its confusing because you have all caps CLASS_CASE and camelCase too... shouldn't the switch case be cleanSearch and not case CLEAN_SEARCH becasue you're calling it via `mapDispatchToProps` so like this:

```
import {
    CLEAN_SEARCH
} from '../actions/types';

import * as utils from '../../utils/udpaterState';

const initialState = {
    itemsSearched: ["foo", "bar"]
}

const reducer= (prevState = initialState, action)=>{
    let newState = null;
    switch(action.type){
        case cleanSearch:
            newState = {itemsSearched: []}
            return utils.updaterState(prevState, newState);
        default:
            return prevState;
    }
}


export default reducer;
```